# Como pasar roles y permisos desde Laravel a un componente Vue.js

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy teniendo algunos problemas pasando roles y permisos de usuarios autenticados a un componente vue.
My objetivo es restringir algunos elementos, como botontes para crear, editar, eliminar.

He seguido las intruccioes de este tutorial:
https://mmccaff.github.io/2018/11/03/laravel-permissions-in-vue-components/?fbclid=IwAR1Oja6yESRJS65huRXPa9SwO2oQdP3W8TwhE_pReUtaK_8rnVAOzixzwXM
Pero no he tenido exito

Acá parte de mi codigo:

RolesAndPermissionsSeeder

```
// create permissions
        //Categorias
        Permission::create(['name' => 'create category']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'update category']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'list categories']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'desactivate category']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'activate category']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete category']);
        //Tareas
        Permission::create(['name' => 'create task']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'update task']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'list tasks']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'desactivate task']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'activate task']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete task']);
    //Tareas de planificador
            $role = Role::create(['name' => 'planificador']);
                $role->givePermissionTo(['list tasks']);
                $role->givePermissionTo(['list categories']);
            // or may be done by chaining
            //TAreas de Aministrador
            $role = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
                //Categorias
                $role->givePermissionTo(['create category']);
                $role->givePermissionTo(['list categories']);
                $role->givePermissionTo(['update category']);
                $role->givePermissionTo(['desactivate category']);
                $role->givePermissionTo(['activate category']);
```

Por ahora puedo, limitar a los usuarios por menus, pero cuando ellos acceden a estoe menu,, por ejemplo el menu de categoria, en don de solo tienen opcion de listar categorias en su rol. pero al entrar a esta seccion, estan didponibles los botones para crear, y lo pueden hacer aun cuando no tienen estas opciones en su rol.

Este es mi admin panel con el que estoy trabajando:
[image: panel]

En mi modelo  User, tengo una funcion para obtener los permisos
 app/User.php:

```
public function getAllPermissionsAttribute() {
    $permissions = [];
    foreach (Permission::all() as $permission) {
        if (Auth::user()->can($permission->name)) {
            $permissions[] = $permission->name;
        }
    }
    return $permissions;
}
```

En mi principal.blade.php, He puesto un arrary javascript..

```
 </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap and necessary plugins -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plantilla.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        'user' => Auth::user()
    ]) !!};
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Mi mixin Permissions.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            $can(permissionName) {
                return Permissions.indexOf(permissionName) !== -1;
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

[image: mixin]

Lo importo en app.js (luego lo compilo npm run dev)

```
 import Permissions from './mixins/Permissions';
    Vue.mixin(Permissions);
```

Finalmente, la restriccion "can" en mi componente Categoria.vue

```
        <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Categorías
            <div v-if="$can('create category')">
                <button type="button" @click="abrirModal('categoria', 'registrar')" class="btn btn-secondary">
                    <i class="icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Nuevo
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Este es el error, que ma señala que lo que tengo en el mixin , está mal

[image: error]

Disculpen por lo extenso de la pregunta, pero quise  ser detallista para poder explicarme lo mejor posible.

Toda ayuda o tip, será bienvenida.
Gracias

Comment: Y a todo esto, que es Permisions? porque lo que dice, es que eso no es una funcion por la cual puedas ejecutar indexof

Comment: puede que te falte algun import? supongo que Permissions sea otro Model y estas trabajando dentro de Categoria, lo otro que se me ocurre que puede pasar es que estas haciendo indexOf a Permisions como modelo no al array del atributo que devuelve la funcion ```getAllPermissionsAttribute()```

Comment: algo que trabaja en conjunto con este paquete `Laravel Permissions` es este otro https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-permission-to-vuejs

Comment: Hola @sgClaudia98, Recuerdo que esto lo resolví utilizando clases de tipo Recurso.
Gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Hola @Dohko19, Está super interesante el package. Lo voy a probar un día de estos. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El Permissions no es un **Array** o un **String**, tal vez esta llegando como un **Object**.

Debes verificar el envío de los datos a la hora de recibir Permissions desde tu Controlador a la vista donde cargas el componente Vue.

```
<script>
    window.Permissions = []

    export default {
        methods: {
            $can(permissionName) {
                return Permissions.indexOf(permissionName) !== -1;
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

En la vista deberías enviarlo de esta forma:

```
</footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap and necessary plugins -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plantilla.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.Permissions = {!! json_encode($permissions) !!};
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
           'user' => Auth::user()
        ]) !!};
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Primero que todo gracias por tu comentario.
Así de buenas a primeras, incluyendo textualmente lo que me enviaste, me da un error de variable permissions, no definida.

Voy a revisarlo con mas detalle.
Saludos

Comment: Hola, fue la idea, no pase el código completo porque no veo donde envias permissions a blade de la vista. En caso de, si necesitas ayuda puedes escribir.

Comment: Si Yohan. Agradezco tu comentario y por supuesto si me puedes ayudar seria genial, ya que estoy atascado aca hace un par de dias.

Comment: Si puedes entra al chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: ya estoy, pero no se como escribirte,,, no habi ausado el chat de stack antes.

Answer (score 1):

intente que los permiso se imprimar antes de app.js, el error se presente ya que al buscar el dato Permissions  se ejecuta antes que se declare

primero va este código y después el app.js

```
  <script>
    @auth
    window.Permissions = <?php echo json_encode(Auth::user()->allPermissions, true); ?>;
    @else
      window.Permissions = [];
    @endauth
     </script>
<!-   y después va este  -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/app.js?v=26.06.03')}}"></script>
```